# Evolution says calendar is read only

Tags: evolution

Evolution says that my calendar (default Google calendar) is read only.  I can edit it via the Web interface with no problem.

The account in question uses 2-factor OAuth2 authentication.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GoogleCalendarWithEvolution

Comment: What calendar is read only? Please help us help you by reviewing http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and then [edit] your post. Thank you!

Comment: @CelticWarrior That link gives a 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: @Demi No, it doesn't. Check your internet connection.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I refreshed and got a valid page.  The 500 error code must have been in cache.  I used the steps provided to set up a CalDAV calendar; problem solved.

Comment: @Demi is it a new calendar? I am running into this problem with an old calendar that used to work just fine in evolution.

Comment: For non-Google readonly calendars, there is a temporary solution here: https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=944768#c5